# UTF-8 encoding with ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, itext

I am having issues with the character encoding for non english characters. Here I am using itext library to generate the pdf.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Document document = new Document();
document.setMargins(-50.0f, -50.0f, 15.0f, 0.0f);
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, byteArrayOutputStream);
document.open();
```

### -----

```
myObj.setByteArrayInputStream(new byteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
```

I tried with the following code

```
myObj.setByteArrayInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8").getBytes()));
```

Comment: You say you're having issues. Please describe these issues. PDF files are binary objects. They don't obey to text encoding rules, and any attempt to apply a text charset to them will irremediably fail and corrupt the result. Don't make any.

Comment: if I use `myObj.setByteArrayInputStream(new byteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));`, then I dont see chinese characters in the pdf generated, However if I use`myObj.setByteArrayInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArrayOutputStream.toString("UTF-8").getBytes()));`, the pdf that is generated is all empty with no data.

Comment: No, a PDF is binary data, the text is internally packed. So do not try to convert the result. You need to create the PDF with for instance Unicode support. A search for PDF and Unicode will help.

Comment: It is interesting that you claim to have *issues with the character encoding for non english characters* but don't show the code you use for adding such characters to the document. Most likely you simply are using a default font (which uses the **WinAnsiEncoding**, essentially some Latin-15-like set of characters). Thus, please show the relevant code and stop trying to destroy a binary file by trying to apply character encodings.

Answer (score 1):

PDF has been designed with a too close coupling between encodings and fonts and is – according to today's standards – unnecessarily difficult to use for non-Western text.

The problem in your code is most likely far more fundamental that just the encoding of the final output stream. It has been correctly pointed out that PDF is a binary format. So don't try to introduce any encoding in the output stream.

Instead, have a look at the iText font examples, e.g. https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/examples/itext-7/itext-7-building-blocks-chapter-1-examples-pdffont and in particular at the examples dealing with foreign text and using `PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H`.

If you still have problem, add the relevant code to your question, in particular the code that sets the font and adds the text to the PDF page.